# How to Index A Search Based Off More Than One Column Using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I am having an issue with indexing a user input to search multiple columns. Here is my code

```
Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Zixi Multicast'] == Group.get()].index
print(Searched_Multicast_Row_Location)
```

This works great, but the problem is, the user may input a value that is in a different column and I would like to index that as well. I tried the following

```
Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Zixi Multicast','Gateway Card Multicast'] == Group.get()].index
print(Searched_Multicast_Row_Location)
```

I am hoping I can store the index of either into a single var

I receive the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\206415779\Anaconda3\envs\FINDIT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('Zixi Multicast', 'Gateway Card Multicast')
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\206415779\Anaconda3\envs\FINDIT\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 221, in Okay
Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Zixi Multicast','Gateway Card Multicast'] == Group.get()].index
File "C:\Users\206415779\Anaconda3\envs\FINDIT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2899, in __getitem__
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\206415779\Anaconda3\envs\FINDIT\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
**KeyError: ('Zixi Multicast', 'Gateway Card Multicast')**
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @David Erickson, was unsure if the error should be in code brackets, now I know.

Comment: Four spaces, or what I do is copy and paste error into my console, highlight all of the code and press tab. Then, paste it back into StackOverflow.

Comment: @David Erickson appreciate the help!

Comment: I've tried the following

`Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1[("IPX Multicast") or ("Gateway Card Multicast")] == Group.get()].index
    print(Searched_Multicast_Row_Location)`

The problem with this is, it now only searches the latter header "Gateway Card Multicast" and when I search for a value under header "IPX Multicast" it does not index the row and I'm left with Null data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what got me what I needed. This searches the user input from "Group.get()" and queries multiple columns, then it indexes the row # so I can grab data from that specific row. Hope this helps someone down the road. From some findings it looks like the "or" operation is not supported within the new version of pandas so you should use | instead.

```
Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Zixi Multicast'] == Group.get()].index | excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Gateway Card Multicast'] == Group.get()].index
print(Searched_Multicast_Row_Location)
```